# Mongoose: populate using virtuals in one query

Tags: mongoose, populate

I followed the messy Mongoose documentation on how to use `populate` while querying, but nothing shows up from my `virtual`.

Here are my models:

Customers model:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CustomerModel = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  payment: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    // ...
  }
});

module.exports = CustomerModel;
```

Account models:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AccountSchema = new Schema({
  customer: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }, {
    // ...
  }
}, {
  toJson: {
    virtuals: true
  }
});

AccountSchema.virtual('customer_id', {
  ref: 'Customer',
  foreignField: 'payment.id',
  localField: 'customer',
  justOne: true
});

module.exports = AccountSchema;
```

The problem here is that when I use `find` chained with `populate` along with the path `customer_id` defined in the Account schema, I am not retrieving the customer's informations.

Here's the query I am doing:

```js
Account.findOne({'customer': 'his_id'}).populate('customer_id').exec(function(err, results) {
  // I am just retrieving the 'his_id', so it has not been populated.
});
```

Any idea how I can do it in one single query? (and by the way, choosing the fields I want to retrieve from the Customer model).

The debug is giving me the following informations for that query:

```
Mongoose: accounts.find({ customer: 'his_id' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: customers.find({ 'payment.id': { '$in': [ 'his_id' ] } }, { fields: {} })
```

Comment: Maybe `mongoose.set('debug', true)` can give you some indicators. What happens when you do `console.log(err, results)` within the callback? Though, random question, why not make AccountSchema `customer` a [reference field](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)  to the customer?

Comment: @Mikey, I just added the debug output to the post. The results from the callback are the Account document only, nothing more (without the Virtual then). About the reference, can I do a reference without the _id ? (I want it to be payment.id).

Comment: Regarding my last statement, why not just do `customer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer', required: true }` ? Then you should be able to do `Account.findOne({ 'customer': 'his_id' }).populate('customer').exec(function(err, account) { ... })`. You would retrieve the customer's info by doing `account.customer._id` or something.

Comment: That's why I specified that I didn't want to use `_id`, but `payment.id`. Can I do that with `ref` ?

Comment: You're right. But how can I specify which field I need it to match (`customer` from Account model to match the `payment.id` from Customer model)? And how can I specify which fields I want it to output? (I don't want to output the `password` field for example). Thanks!

Comment: Ok I get it, my apologies: your use of `virtual` makes sense. I would try running the 2nd query separately to see what it outputs. In terms of your second question, you should be able to [use the `select` option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in a `populate` object (scroll to **Query conditions and other options**) .